# How can I change the aesthetic mapping for confidence intervals when using ggcompetingrisks?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

The confidence interval colors don't match the line colors. (picture included. I'm aware the plot is not very informative since I used a small subset of the data for this example.)

ggcompetingrisks() is from the survminer package.

```
p3 <- ggcompetingrisks(fit = x, 
                       multiple_panels = F, 
                       ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
                       coef = 1.96, #95% CI
                       conf.int = T,
                       xlim = c(0, 15),
                       ylim = c(0, 0.1),
                       xlab = "Days", 
                       ylab = "Probability",
                       title = "Cumulative Incidence by Time Period") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), #center title
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)), #pad y axis label
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))) + #pad x axis label
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Period 1","Period 2","Period 3"),  
                     values = c("#9ef0f0", "#08bdba", "#0f62fe"), 
                     name = element_blank())   # do not name legend
p3$mapping <- aes(x = time, y = est, colour = group, linetype = event) # overwrite aes to flip linetype and color mappings

p3
```

It produces [image: this plot].

Below is the code to reproduce the cuminc object for the plot.

```
x <- 
structure(list(`1 1` = list(time = c(0, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10, 11, 11, 14, 14, 15, 15), 
                            est = c(0, 0, 0.002714939, 0.002714939, 0.025168630, 0.025168630, 0.029488245, 0.029488245, 0.035423797, 0.035423797, 0.04164908, 0.04164908, 0.04553497, 0.04553497, 0.04689997), 
                            var = c(0, 0, 2.452515e-06, 2.452515e-06, 2.289665e-05, 2.289665e-05, 2.734325e-05, 2.734325e-05, 3.402077e-05, 3.402077e-05,4.129261e-05, 4.129261e-05, 4.597699e-05, 4.597699e-05, 4.770832e-05)), 
               
               `2 1` = list(time = c(0, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14), 
                            est = c(0, 0, 0.001256405, 0.001256405, 0.005138794, 0.005138794, 0.013189197, 0.013189197, 0.016127006, 0.016127006,0.02671412, 0.02671412, 0.02829462, 0.02829462, 0.04365371), 
                            var = c(0, 0, 1.578565e-06, 1.578565e-06, 6.577619e-06, 6.577619e-06, 1.719998e-05, 1.719998e-05, 2.140657e-05, 2.140657e-05, 3.681209e-05, 3.681209e-05, 3.918992e-05, 3.918992e-05, 6.379430e-05)), 
               
               `3 1` = list(time = c(0, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8,  9,  9, 10, 10), 
                            est = c(0, 0, 0.001532092, 0.001532092, 0.004695122, 0.004695122, 0.007942922, 0.007942922, 0.011258385, 0.011258385, 0.01647932, 0.01647932, 0.01826306, 0.01826306, 0.02565641), 
                            var = c(0,0,2.347337e-06,2.347337e-06,7.326912e-06,7.326912e-06,1.254441e-05,1.254441e-05,1.794701e-05,1.794701e-05, 2.681038e-05, 2.681038e-05, 2.989403e-05, 2.989403e-05, 4.302871e-05)),
              
               Tests = structure(c(74.0658010607094, 89.5877719522838, 3.10862446895044e-15, 0, 4, 4), 
                                 .Dim = 2:3, 
                                 .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("stat", "pv", "df")))), class = "cuminc")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit complicated, but I found out that in the `fill` column of the data, all the colours are the same. That's why you have the same color for each CI. To prevent that, you can create p3 as a `ggplot` object using `ggplot_build`. Next you conditionally replace the values in `fill` column of the data to the right column. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
x <- 
  structure(list(`1 1` = list(time = c(0, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10, 11, 11, 14, 14, 15, 15), 
                              est = c(0, 0, 0.002714939, 0.002714939, 0.025168630, 0.025168630, 0.029488245, 0.029488245, 0.035423797, 0.035423797, 0.04164908, 0.04164908, 0.04553497, 0.04553497, 0.04689997), 
                              var = c(0, 0, 2.452515e-06, 2.452515e-06, 2.289665e-05, 2.289665e-05, 2.734325e-05, 2.734325e-05, 3.402077e-05, 3.402077e-05,4.129261e-05, 4.129261e-05, 4.597699e-05, 4.597699e-05, 4.770832e-05)), 
                 
                 `2 1` = list(time = c(0, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14), 
                              est = c(0, 0, 0.001256405, 0.001256405, 0.005138794, 0.005138794, 0.013189197, 0.013189197, 0.016127006, 0.016127006,0.02671412, 0.02671412, 0.02829462, 0.02829462, 0.04365371), 
                              var = c(0, 0, 1.578565e-06, 1.578565e-06, 6.577619e-06, 6.577619e-06, 1.719998e-05, 1.719998e-05, 2.140657e-05, 2.140657e-05, 3.681209e-05, 3.681209e-05, 3.918992e-05, 3.918992e-05, 6.379430e-05)), 
                 
                 `3 1` = list(time = c(0, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8,  9,  9, 10, 10), 
                              est = c(0, 0, 0.001532092, 0.001532092, 0.004695122, 0.004695122, 0.007942922, 0.007942922, 0.011258385, 0.011258385, 0.01647932, 0.01647932, 0.01826306, 0.01826306, 0.02565641), 
                              var = c(0,0,2.347337e-06,2.347337e-06,7.326912e-06,7.326912e-06,1.254441e-05,1.254441e-05,1.794701e-05,1.794701e-05, 2.681038e-05, 2.681038e-05, 2.989403e-05, 2.989403e-05, 4.302871e-05)),
                 
                 Tests = structure(c(74.0658010607094, 89.5877719522838, 3.10862446895044e-15, 0, 4, 4), 
                                   .Dim = 2:3, 
                                   .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("stat", "pv", "df")))), class = "cuminc") 

library(survminer)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
p3 <- ggcompetingrisks(fit = x, 
                       multiple_panels = F, 
                       ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
                       coef = 1.96, #95% CI
                       conf.int = T,
                       xlim = c(0, 15),
                       ylim = c(0, 0.1),
                       xlab = "Days", 
                       ylab = "Probability",
                       title = "Cumulative Incidence by Time Period") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), #center title
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)), #pad y axis label
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))) + #pad x axis label
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Period 1","Period 2","Period 3"),  
                     values = c("#9ef0f0", "#08bdba", "#0f62fe"), 
                     name = element_blank()) +   # do not name legend
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Period 1"),  
                    values = c("#9ef0f0", "#08bdba", "#0f62fe"))
p3$mapping <- aes(x = time, y = est, colour = group, linetype = event, fill = event) # overwrite aes to flip linetype and color mappings

p3

p_build <- ggplot_build(p3)

p_build$data[[2]]$fill
#>  [1] "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0"
#>  [8] "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0"
#> [15] "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0"
#> [22] "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0"
#> [29] "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0"
#> [36] "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0"
#> [43] "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0" "#9ef0f0"

p_build$data[[1]] <- p_build$data[[1]] %>% mutate(fill = case_when(colour == "#9ef0f0" ~ "#9ef0f0",
                                                                   colour == "#08bdba" ~ "#08bdba",
                                                                   colour == "#0f62fe" ~ "#0f62fe"))


grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(p_build))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>